# Problems with JSoup in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I have a problem using JSoup on my Android application because I have an NetworkOnMainThreadException. I'm using an AsyncTask for get the information of the tags of my web, but I don't know if I am doing it correctly so I need help to do this. Here is the code:

The main Activity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
    tagsSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String myPage = "http://www.mypage.com";
    TagGetter tG = new TagGetter();
    ArrayList<Tag> a;
    tG.setPage(myPage);
    try {
        a = tG.execute(myPage).get();
        this.fillSpinner(a);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void fillSpinner(ArrayList<Tag> a) {

    String[] numTags = new String[a.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        numTags[i] = a.get(i).getTitle();
    }
    arrayAdapterTags = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,numTags);
    tagsSP.setAdapter(arrayAdapterTags);
}
```

And here is the AsyncTask code:

```
public class TagGetter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Tag>> {
Document html;
String className, page;
ArrayList<Tag> tags;

/**
 * This method is from the AsyncTask class. It will run with the method "execute"
 *
 * @param params
 * @return
 */
@Override
protected ArrayList<Tag> doInBackground(String... params) {
    this.tags = getTags();
    return this.tags;
}

/**
 * This method allows to you to set a url where you can get the tags.
 *
 * @param url
 */
public void setPage(String url) {
    this.page = url;
}

/**
 * This method gives to you an ArrayList of tags.
 *
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<Tag> getTags() {
    ArrayList<Tag> tgs = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    try {
        html = getConnect(page);
        className = "tag_col_0";
        Elements items = html.getElementsByClass(className);
        String[] col_0 = getValuesTag(html, "tag_col_0", "b");
        String[] col_1 = getValuesTag(html, "tag_col_1", "b");
        String[] col_2 = getValuesTag(html, "tag_col_2", "b");
        String[] col_3 = getValuesTag(html, "tag_col_3", "b");
        String[] tag_names = new String[col_0.length + col_1.length + col_2.length + col_3.length];
        tag_names = appendArrayString(col_0, col_1, tag_names);
        tag_names = appendArrayString(tag_names, col_2, tag_names);
        tag_names = appendArrayString(tag_names, col_3, tag_names);

        String[] url_0 = getURL(html, "tag_col_0", "href");
        String[] url_1 = getURL(html, "tag_col_1", "href");
        String[] url_2 = getURL(html, "tag_col_2", "href");
        String[] url_3 = getURL(html, "tag_col_3", "href");
        String[] tag_links = new String[col_0.length + col_1.length + col_2.length + col_3.length];
        tag_links = appendArrayString(url_0, url_1, tag_links);
        tag_links = appendArrayString(tag_links, url_2, tag_links);
        tag_links = appendArrayString(tag_links, url_3, tag_links);

        int n = tag_names.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tgs.add(new Tag(tag_names[i], page+"/"+ tag_links[i]));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tgs;
}

/**
 * This method returns the conection to a web page.
 *
 * @param link
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public Document getConnect(String link) throws IOException {
    return Jsoup.connect(link).get();
}

/**
 * This method allows to you to append two arrays.
 *
 * @param arrayX
 * @param arrayY
 * @param build
 * @return
 */
public String[] appendArrayString(String[] arrayX, String[] arrayY, String[] build) {
    int x = arrayX.length;
    int y = arrayY.length;
    int n = 0;
    build = new String[x + y];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        build[i] = arrayX[i];
        n = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        build[i + n] = arrayY[i];
    }
    return build;
}

/**
 * This method returns the url of a tag.
 *
 * @param item = the connection
 * @param name  = the name of the main class (or tag)
 * @param prin = the name of the attribute you're looking for
 * @return
 */
public String[] getURL(Document item, String name, String prin) {

    Elements e = item.getElementsByClass(name);
    int n = e.size();
    String[] elements = new String[n];
    if (e != null && n > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Element element = (Element) e.get(i);
            elements[i] = element.getElementsByAttribute(prin).text();

        }
    }
    return elements;
}

/**
 * This method returns the name of the tag.
 *
 * @param item = the connection
 * @param name  = the name of the main class (or tag)
 * @param prin = the name of the tag you're looking for
 * @return
 */
public String[] getValuesTag(Document item, String name, String prin) {

    Elements e = item.getElementsByClass(name);
    int n = e.size();
    String[] elements = new String[n];
    if (e != null && n > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Element element = (Element) e.get(i);
            elements[i] = element.getElementsByTag(prin).text();

        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

The Tag object's constructor only require the tag name and the tag url.

So where is the problem?

PD: I have the *android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE* and *android.permission.INTERNET* in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

Therefore, try to use AsyncTask As below :

```
   public class ForgotPasswordTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {}
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            /* forming th java.net.URL object */
            URL url = new URL("http://www.mypage.com");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();


            /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
            if (statusCode ==  200) {



                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;


                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

//get result/response generated from onPostExecute()

    }
}
```

Comment: With this class I can get the html code, but I want to know how could I use the JSoup methods to get the info. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: you have to do html parsing which is done by some methods, if you have any problem in html parsing then i can also help to parse the HTML data, which i know. Thank you